# Replacing a string in the beginning of some rows in two columns with another string in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a tab separated text file. In column 1 and 2 there are family and individual ids that start with a character followed by number as follow:

```
HG1005 HG1005
HG1006 HG1006
HG1007 HG1007
NA1008 NA1008
NA1009 NA1009
```

I would like to replace NA with HG in both the columns. I am very new to linux and tried the following code and some others:

```
awk '{sub("NA","HG",$2)';print}' input file > output file
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try charging `sub` to `gsub`: `awk '{gsub("NA","HG");print}' input file > output file` once?

Comment: you can also use `sed 's/NA/HG/g' ip > op`.. there's probably a duplicate somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$2` in your call to `sub` only replaces the first occurrence of `NA` in the second field.

Note that while `sed` is more typical for such scenarios:

```sh
sed 's/NA/HG/g' inputfile > outputfile
```

you can still use `awk`:

```sh
awk '{gsub("NA","HG")}1' inputfile > outputfile
```

See the [**online demo**](https://ideone.com/oANzro).

Since there is no input variable in `gsub` (that performs multiple search and replaces) the default `$0` is used, i.e. the whole record, the current line, and the code above is equal to `awk '{gsub("NA","HG",$0)}1' inputfile > outputfile`.

The `1` at the end triggers printing the current record, it is a shorter variant of `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer now, use `gsub` in spite of `sub` here. Because it will globally substitute NA to HG here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub("NA","HG");print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

OR use following in case you have several fields and you want to perform substitution only in 1st and 2nd fields.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub("NA","HG",$1);sub("NA","HG",$2);print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Change `sub` to `gsub` in 2nd code in case multiple occurrences of NA needs to be changed within field itself.

Answer (score 1):

Notice `/^NA/` position at the beginning of field:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /^NA/) sub(/^NA/,"HG",$(i))} 1' file
HG1005 HG1005
HG1006 HG1006
HG1007 HG1007
HG1008 HG1008
HG1009 HG1009
```

and save it:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /^NA/) sub(/^NA/,"HG",$(i))} 1' file > outputfile
```

If you have a tab as separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /^NA/) sub(/^NA/,"HG",$(i))} 1' file > outputfile
```